# Update array of objects based on the object passed

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016

I have an array of objects that has the following format,

```
const options = [
  { key: 1, text: "Name", value: "name", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 2, text: "Time", value: "time", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 3, text: "Type", value: "type", icon: "sort" }
];
```

Now based on the input passed which of format  {fieldName,order} I have to modify the array. Basically order will take two values "asc" or "desc" and the fieldName will take any of the values in the `value` property of options array.

For Example : { fieldName: "name", order : "asc"} or { fieldName: "type", order: "desc"}

Now basically based this order , I have modify the `icon` field of the source array for that field.

If  `order` is **asc**, then change the `icon` property for that field to `sort up` .If its order is **desc**, then change the `icon` property for that field to `sort down`

Example

```
1) sortBy: { fielName: "name", order:"asc"} 

//Output
[
  { key: 1, text: "Name", value: "name", icon: "sort up" },
  { key: 2, text: "Time", value: "time", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 3, text: "Type", value: "type", icon: "sort" }
];

2) sortBy: { fielName: "type", order:"desc"} 

//Output
[
  { key: 1, text: "Name", value: "name", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 2, text: "Time", value: "time", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 3, text: "Type", value: "type", icon: "sort down"}
];
```

**It should update `icon` only of the field passed to it, and rest fields `icon` should be set to "sort"**

This is what I tried

```
const options = [
  { key: 1, text: "Name", value: "name", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 2, text: "Time", value: "time", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 3, text: "Type", value: "type", icon: "sort" }
];

function updateArray(obj)
{
   const newArr = options.map(item => {
     if(item.name === obj.fieldName) {
    return {...item, icon: obj.order === "desc" ? "sort-desc" :"sort-asc" };
    }
    return {...item};
   });
   return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
const options = [
  { key: 1, text: "Name", value: "name", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 2, text: "Time", value: "time", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 3, text: "Type", value: "type", icon: "sort" }
];
function sorta(op,options){
   field =op.fielName
   newarray=[]
   options.forEach(o=>{
     if(o.value==field){
      op.order=="asc"?f="up":f="down"
      o.icon="sort-"+f
      newarray.push(o)
     }
      else newarray.push(o)
  })
     return newarray
}

console.log(sorta({ fielName: "name", order:"asc"},options ))
```

Comment: Thanks. This over rides the existing array. I am using this in the context of react

Comment: you want a new array?

Comment: And yeah looks like your hardcoding here,  o.icon="sort-"+op.order. Actually its "sort down" if "decsc" and "sort up" if asc. Sorry added the edit

Comment: but in your question you used sort desc and sort asc i don't anywhere in your question up and down, can you point me where that is mentioned in your question?

Comment: yes I mentioned in the comment:) Sorry Forgot to add that

Comment: I have fixed all the issues addressed and updated my answer check it out

Answer (score 0):

Your function works, but you are trying to access a non-existent property.

I believe it should be:

```
if(item.value === obj.fieldName) {
  ...
}
```

Demo:

```js
const options = [
  { key: 1, text: "Name", value: "name", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 2, text: "Time", value: "time", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 3, text: "Type", value: "type", icon: "sort" }
];

function updateArray(obj)
{
   const newArr = options.map(item => {
     if(item.value === obj.fieldName) {
    return {...item, icon: obj.order === "desc" ? "sort-desc" :"sort-asc" };
    }
    return {...item};
   });
   return newArr;
};

console.log(updateArray({fieldName: 'type', order: 'desc'}));
console.log(updateArray({fieldName: 'time', order: 'asc'}));
console.log(updateArray({fieldName: 'name', order: 'desc'}));
```

Comment: @li97 Are you sure? See the demo.